# Firebase sample function "generateThumbnail" won't deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, thumbnails

I can't get sample function `generateThumbnail` from the Firebase [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions) repo to deploy to my project. I get error message when running `firebase deploy`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
                                                                         ^
```

I have cloned the repo and left it untouched so code should be valid. Firebase is initiated in my project since other storage functions is working properly so I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I am running `npm` v6.9.1-next.0, `node` v11.10.0 and `firebase` v6.5.0 locally if that has got anything to do with it..

The Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) seems a bit outdated on some places also so it's quite hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Suggestion: delete "async" and see if that gets you past the compile error...

Comment: @paulsm4 after removing all `async` and `await` it compiled successfully. Any idea why? Thanks btw

Comment: ...however the function fails in the Firebase console: `Unhandled rejection` but I guess I am making progress :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running node 11 on your desktop, but that's not the same version of node that Cloud Functions runs by default.  If you don't change the default, it runs node 6, which does not support async/await syntax.  Either you will have to remove async/await and replace it with regular promises, or you will have to tell the Firebase CLI to deploy to node 8, which does support async/await.  At the time of this writing, the node 8 runtime is in beta in Cloud Functions.

To deploy to node 8, put the following at the top level of your package.json, as described by [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version):

```
"engines": {"node": "8"}
```

Comment: I was suspecting something like this would be the issue. Thank you very much for making it clear!